# Truncation of tag with "xsl:value-of select"

Tags: xslt

When I execute the following xsl I get a truncated tag pair instead of the complete tag(see the very end of the question).

Original code:

```
<xsl:template match="node()\@*">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()\@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CONFIG">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=" ../ID/.='2'">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>STANDARD</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="NAME">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=" ../ID/.='2'">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>DEVELOPMENT</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Modified code:

```
<xsl:template match="node()\@*">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()\@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CONFIG">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=" ../ID/.='2'">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>STD</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="KEY">
            <xsl:value-of select='0'/>
        <xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="NAME">
            <xsl:value-of select="'DEVELOPMENT'"/>
        <xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

So the idea is instead of just setting CONFIG to "STANDARD", I'm also trying to set KEY.
And instead of processing the same "query" twice, I moved the setting of NAME up.

KEY is set correctly; but I get the truncated
    `<NAME>`
instead of
    `<NAME>DEVELOPMENT</NAME>`

I'm obviously not an XML guy, just doing some maintenance.  Any leads or advice are appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the backslash is a typo for `|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create attributes after an element's content has been output.

Move `<xsl:attribute>` above `<xsl:text>`.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CONFIG[../ID = '2']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:attribute name="KEY">0<xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="NAME">DEVELOPMENT<xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:text>STD</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It seems I know even less than I thought.

I picked up on your saying "can't create an attribute", which helped, because I wasn't trying to create, that was a modify.

What I'm really trying to do is match on ID, and change ID, CONFIG, and NAME.

Since this is maintenance, I'm going to punt and just repeat the match/test logic a third time, which seems to work.  It just bugs the heck out of me because it seems like I should be able to match just once.

And yes, the \ was really a | (I can't cut and paste from this system, so I have to transcribe).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Creating an attribute with `<xsl:attribute>` causes any existing attribute with that name to be overwritten. Effectively that is a modify, just like you seem to want. (Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it has solved your problem.)

Comment: It works out that it was indeed working.  The problem was that the xml editor I'm using (XMLSpy) has a built-in engine and allows the MS parser.  For some reason the built-in parser doesn't show the correct result of the transform.  So it looked like the end-tag wasn't there, but it was.  6 hours shot to hell; and some kludgey code that I'm not going back to update.  But that's again for the information.